# How to split a column in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, string, split

I have a column which value is combine two elements, Just like "Class_Name"。For example , "Websites_Google"。But for some  historical reasons, there have some special value which have no "Class_" prefix, like "yahoo".

Now I need to extract the class from columns. If there is no "class_" prefix , i expect return "" .
I just try SUBSTRING_INDEX functions like this:

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(column1, '_', 1) .......
```

It works very well when the value have "class_", but in the no "class_" situation, it return the whole value, "yahoo" return "yahoo", not the empty string which i want.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IF` [to check if the underscore is there](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97334/2):

```
select if(locate('_',column1)=0,'',SUBSTRING_INDEX(column1, '_', 1))
from mytable
```

Comment: Thx. It's a beautiful solution.

Answer (score 2):

Kindly check with the following

```
select case when CHARINDEX ('_', column1)>0 then SUBSTRING_INDEX(column1, '_', 1) else '' end .....
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a mysql function.
Here's a working example:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `test`.`split_class` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `test`.`split_class` (`class` varchar(25)) RETURNS varchar(25)
BEGIN

DECLARE `tmp1` varchar(25);
DECLARE `tmp2` varchar(25);
DECLARE `ret` varchar(25);

  set `tmp1` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`class`, '_', 1);
  set `tmp2` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`class`, '_', -1);
  set `ret` = '';

  IF `tmp1` != `tmp2`
    then set `ret` = `tmp1`;
  END IF;

  RETURN `ret`;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then, try the select

```
SELECT split_class(last) FROM test.`table` t;
```